# Create a slideshow from a website

Tags: slideshow

I'd like to make use of some kind of (AI?) software to produce a slideshow of my website's features.

The aim is to use the slideshow in a video on YouTube.

I'd like the software to extract key details from the website when creating the slideshow, such as:

- Products & Services
- Headings from each Product and service web page
- Featured image from each Product and Service web page

I've searched Google for:

- create an automated slideshow from a website URL

& searched `softwarerecs.stackexchange.com` for:

- create an slideshow from website

but found no relevant results.

I'm happy to pay up to ~US$100 for this software.

Help appreciated.